# Printer recognized but not printing. CUPS

Tags: debian, printing, printer, cups

I'm using a HP 1000 J110 connected to a server which I access via ssh. I use `lsusb` and it appears there. Then, I Pasted the PPD on the `/etc/cups/ppd/` folder... Is the ppd my pc uses to print when attached directly to the PC.

I Use `lpstat -p`

and it shows the printer there :

```
printer DESKJET-1000-J110 is idle.  enabled since Fri 22 Mar 2013 08:05:33 PM UTC
```

Then i use:

```
lp -d DESKJET-1000-J110 filetoprint.txt
```

request id is DESKJET-1000-J110-111 (1 file(s))

and it appears that the file is sent to print, and actually appear as completed, but it just doesn't print anything.

Also tryed with HPLip And when trying to run `hp-setup -i` it says:

`error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality.`

I checked and this printer IS supported by hplip.

What am I missing? ..

Comment: Is it out of paper or toner or something?

Comment: Did you try to install hplip? hplip is the hp official drivers. You can find it on debian repository.

Comment: @Brigo Yes. I already tryied Hplip... it says: `error: No device selected/specified or that supports this functionality. ` .. And i checked and This printer IS supported by hplip..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was not that complicated. I used the following code: (Erased before the existing printers using lpadmin -x PrinterName)

To view my URI:

```
lpinfo -v
```

I got this:

```
:~# lpinfo -v
network http
network socket
direct scsi
network lpd
network ipp
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
direct usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2
network beh
```

The `direct usb` part is the URI.

I had already a ppd file. So I copied it to `/etc/cups/ppd/`

Then I added the printer using:

```
:~# lpadmin -p Deskjet-1000-J110-series -E -v usb://HP/Deskjet%201000%20J110%20series?serial=CN19S21RWB05D2 -m /etc/cups/ppd/Deskjet-1000-J110-series.ppd
```

I got this error:
`lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file!`

As it was already specified (the ppd file) .. I ran a test

`lp -d Deskjet-1000-J110-series fileToPrint`

And.. printed...

Answer (score 1):

Running `hp-check -t` will give you more information about the status of the printer -- specifically, the **DISCOVERED USB DEVICES** and **INSTALLED CUPS PRINTER QUEUES**.

Have you verified to ensure that `cups` is running?

```
% /sbin/service cups status
cupsd (pid  1453) is running...
```

How are you verifying that the file has been sent and **appear[s] as completed**?

Comment: Cups is running fine. I Have another printer here and I can print fine with it. Just having troubles with the HP1000. Also i know that the file is completed because after sending to print I try to cancel the last job and it says `cancel: cancel-job failed: Job #113 is already completed - can't cancel.` .. any ideas?

Comment: In the `Installed cups printer queues` there are my 2 printers.. but in the hp-1000 is just Type and URI. It doesnt view the ppd as with my other printer..